# Validate Django model form with excluded fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form ReviewForm that allows one user to review another user (source of the review and target of the review).  I would like to check that the user does not review herself and I think the place to do that should be in the ReviewForm itself.  However, the two users (source and target) are not part of the form since they are selected through the UI before.  What is the cleanest way of doing this?  Right now I am doing the validation in the view but I don't find that nice.

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Review
        fields=["title", "content"]


class Review(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(blank=True)
    source=models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name="reviews_by")
    target=models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name="reviews_of")


def new_review(request,profile_id):
    form=ReviewForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        review=models.Review()
        review.source=request.user.profile
        review.target=models.Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST, instance = review)
        if request.user.profile.id == int(profile_id):
            form.errors["__all__"]= "Don't review yourself!"
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("profile"))
        else:
            return render(request,"reviews/new.html",{"form":form})
    return render(request,"reviews/new.html",{"form":form})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        if self.instance.source == self.instance.target:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You cannot review your entity")
        return super(ReviewForm, self).clean()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Review
        fields=["title", "content"]
```